# How does operations P & V work and set the semaphore value?

Tags: java, semaphore

I'm confused about how operations P & V work in semaphores(particulary in Java if there is a difference).

As far as I know, operation P decrements the value of a semaphore, if the new value is <0 then the process is blocked, and operation V does the opposite. But, can operation P decrement a semaphore value to a negative one? If so, does it mean operation V has to increment the semaphore to a positive value in order to give the process a permit?

Let's say we have 4 processes(or threads), called A,B,C and D. And a semaphore S set to 2. The processes are called respectevly as created(A,B,C then D). Means A will go first then B second ...etc

```
Semaphore S=new Semaphore(2);
S.acquire();
print(Thread.currentThread().getName() +" is in with S value=" + S.value);
S.release();
print(Thread.name +" is out S value=" + S.value);
```

From my understading of how they work, I say the output would be something like this:

> A is in with S=1
>
> B is in with S=0
>
> C tries to go in with S=-1 (Is this correct?)
>
> B tries to go in with S=-2 (Is this correct?)
>
> A is out with S=-1
>
> C is in with S=-1
>
> B is out with S=0
>
> D is in with S=0
>
> C is out with S=1
>
> D is out with S=2

P.S: `S.value` doesn't really exist, I just put it there to show what I'm trying to see/show.

Comment: *operation P decrements the value of a semaphore*: maybe, maybe not. Why don't you post the code of P()? We would **know** what it does. How about giving meaningful names to methods, that respect the Java naming conventions, instead of P and V

Comment: @JBNizet I already used semaphores in C long ago, trying to use them again in Java, I put the tag because I don't really know if there is a difference between how C manipulates the semaphore and how Java does. P() isn't a real method, it just explains what the semaphore is used for.

Comment: Have you read the javadoc of Semaphore and its methods? Because it explains how it works. What is unclear in this javadoc? Instead of trying to guess what some fake code would do, why don't you write real code and test it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea of decrementing the value from an N number is to enable upto N calls not to block.

When the value reaches 0, the next call will block and the value will not be decremented, it will remain 0.

Upon release the value will be incremented to 1, and the waiting processes will be signaled to try to acquire the relesed lock. Only one will be able to do it and the rest will remained blocked.

When all processes release their semaphores, the value will return to be N.

Comment: When a blocked call gets a permit, does it decrement the semaphore value? Or it leaves it as it was? For example C is blocked at 0 and A releases the permit, thus the semaphore is set to 1, does C decrement it to 0?

Comment: When A releases the semaphore is incremented to 1 and C (and anyother process waiting) is/are signaled and try to get the permit released by A. Which ever gets it, decrements the semaphore to 0 again and continues, the rest who failed to acquire the semaphore, continue waiting.

Comment: I've done some researches the whole day on how the P and V operations works, from what I found and understood, I beleive that these operations work differently but to the same goal depending on which system they're used. Java  uses the System V semaphores, which implement the P operation in a way the semaphore won't be decreemented to a negative value, while Linux(C) uses the POSIX semaphores,  which implements the P operation in a way that the value of the semaphore can be negative. Is this correct?